# I am working on CodeIgniter framework with datatables and data loading speed is very slow

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, datatable, datatables

I am using datatable for many purposes like pagination, search, hide/show column etc but when it comes to load data to the page it take a lot of time .There are round about 5000 entries in database let me show you the code here for proper understanding
Datatables Script:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready( function () {
   oTable = $('#myTable , #complete_ride , #incomplete_ride').DataTable({
   "dom": 'Btip',
   "deferRender": true,
   "ordering" : false,
   "pageLength": 20,
   "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
   "scrollX": true,
  buttons: ['colvis','excel' , 'csv'],
  });

 $('#search_item').keyup(function(){
  oTable.search($(this).val()).draw();
  });
  $('input.toggle').on( 'click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get the column API object
    var column = oTable.column( $(this).attr('data-column') );
    // Toggle the visibility
    column.visible( ! column.visible() );
 });
 });
 </script>
```

Here is the code of Controller:

```
function index()
{
 $data['user_basic'] = $this->User_basic_model->get_all_user_basic();
 $data['_view'] = 'user_basic/index';
 $this->load->view('layouts/main',$data);
}
```

and code of model:

```
 function get_all_user_basic()
 {
    $this->db->order_by('user_id', 'desc');
    $this->db->select('table1.user_id,
                       table1.full_name,
                       table1.email,
                       table1.phone,
                       table1.password,
                       table1.date_of_birth,
                       table1.gender,
                       table1.address,
                       table1.cnic_no,
                       table1.reg_no,
                       table1.status,
                       table1.access_level,
                       table2.institute_id,
                       table2.institute_name,
                       table3.department_id,
                       table3.department_name,
                       table1.total_rides,
                       table1.total_distance,
                       table1.total_calories,
                       table1.wallet_amount,
                       table1.wallet_expiry,
                       table1.reffered_by,
                       table1.refferel_key,
                       table1.failed_login_attempts,
                       table1.last_login,
                       table1.last_login_ip,
                       table1.creation_date,
                       table1.update_date,
                       table1.delete_date,
                       table1.total_time');
    $this->db->from('table1');
    $this->db->join('table2' , 'table1.institute_id = table2.institute_id' , 'left outer');
    $this->db->join('table3' , 'table1.department_id = table3.department_id' , 'left outer');
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

Comment: You should add indexes in the columns that you're joining on.

Comment: Did you consider using limits for your pagination? Why loading all entries when you will only show few?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you display all of your 5000 entries to the view. 
Looping 5000 times in view is a big pain!

Try to use Datatable server side processing feature. You can take a look here https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side

The [demo](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/server-side_processing.html) is with 5M data and it's fast

Comment: Hey #Ageng actually with server-side-processing i have solve the issue of page loading but pagination and search is not working at all

Comment: Here is a code
`$(document).ready( function () {
$('#myTabletest').DataTable({
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
"paging": true,
"order": [],
"ajax": {
 "url": "<?php echo base_url() . 'User_basic/get_data'; ?>",
 "type": "POST",
 "dataSrc": ""
},
 "columns":[
    {'data': 'user_id'},
 {'data': 'full_name'},
 {'data': 'email'},
 {'data': 'phone'},
        etc...
   
  ]

  // method:'post',
 });
} )`

Comment: And yes because your model doesn't catch the search query. You can use [link] (https://github.com/cryogenix/Ignited-Datatables) to make it more simple

Comment: @YasirMehmood mark as answered if your question has been solved